# preposition plus as little noise as possible

Tags: prepositional-phrases

> The side-passage door was fastened; I opened it with **as little noise
>   as possible**. (Jane Eyre)

What do you call grammatically ‘as little noise as possible’ after ‘with’? I’m very confused because the phase is not a typical prepositional phase nor a noun phrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entire phrase *with as little noise as possible* is an adverbial phrase of manner. It could be replaced with the single adverb *quietly*.

The portion following *with* is a disguised noun phrase. It could be rewritten as *minimum noise*. So *as little ... as possible* is an idiomatic expression that acts adjectivally to modify the noun *noise*.